# svg gradient not working in app due to fill path relativity

Tags: javascript, css, url, svg, fill

I have a SVG with lineargradient which works fine when opened independently in the browser. When I embed it in my single page app, the gradient does not appear.

When I assign the svg as backgroundimage or img src, it works fine. Also ,when I modify the fill url with respect to my app url(eg. **fill: url(#graidentId) becomes fill: url('path#gradientId')**), it works fine.

I want the svg to be independent of the code.And not modify the fill path in my code.

I do not want to use it as backgroundimage or img src as well.

Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to generate SVGs such that this is fixed.

Comment: Stop using the `<base>` tag in your single page app.

Comment: this worked but screwed rest of the app URL... So my problem still remains unresolved :)

Comment: How do you embed it? Can you show your code?